# Pass AWS credentials in same shell in Makefile

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile

I want to assign a result of shell script to a variable in next way:

```
SOME_KEY = $(shell aws secretsmanager get-value ...)
```

And for a specific target, i want to overwrite AWS credentials:

```
get-some-key: export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(SOME_OTHER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
get-some-key: export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(SOME_OTHER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
get-some-key:
        echo $$SOME_KEY
```

I expected to get a value, but i don't, since `$(shell)` command uses initial AWS credentials.
What is a way to correctly pass AWS credentials to same shell?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  Please take a step back and explain how these variables work together.  Perhaps you can show how you would do this successfully from a shell prompt.  I most especially don't understand what the `echo $$SOME_KEY` is expected to do; this prints the _shell_ variable `SOME_KEY`, but as far as you show in your makefile you never set that shell variable.

Comment: My bad. If i have env variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID + AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, that allows me to perform aws operations, with provided by aws policies. And i want to ovewrite them for a specific target, to be able to run some of aws command (get-secret-value in this case). So, echo $$SOME_KEY should perform aws operation with ovewrited AWS credentials

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tool for the job? It looks to me like you need Ansible/Terraform/CloudFormation, not Make.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand what you're trying to do. You have aws access credential environment variables set outside make. You want to use overriding creds when calling this target. If that is correct, consider the following:

```
id = aws sts get-caller-identity

get-id-with-creds: export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=redacted
get-id-with-creds: export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=redacted
get-id-with-creds: get-id

get-id:
    $(id)
```

And I verified that works:

```
make get-id # gives back my default user
make get-id-with-creds # gives back my user with creds in Makefile
```

Comment: `shell echo $X` is unnecessary, Make automatically imports env variables if you don't have your variables with the same name.

Comment: It is illustrative. To show the change with the target specific variable. What you say is precisely the point. Without setting it, you shows the value set in the environment outside make.

Comment: I agree with HolyBlackCat.  Using the `shell` function just confuses everything, because environment variables are not exported to `shell` (in the current releases of GNU make).  You're already using this variable inside a recipe, which is already running in the shell.  You should just have `id = aws sts get-caller-identity` without `shell`, then you can just run it in the recipe as `$(id)`, you don't need `echo $(id)`.  You don't have to put the variables explicitly in the command at all.

Comment: Okay. I think I misunderstood initially. I have updated the entry. The only part that doesn't seem to work for me @MadScientist is removing the variables from the top line. Without them, the defaults from the environment are used. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Disregard that last comment, it does work if you include `export` in the target specific variables. So this should be sufficient.

Comment: Nice.  Good one!

Comment: Yeah, i agreed with you, in this case (with aws sts get-caller-identity) everything works fine, but i have to assign a result from `aws secretsmanager get-value` to a variable, and for this purpose i have to use `$(shell aws secretsmanager ...)`
For example, i would like to store the result of `aws sts get-caller-identity` command to a variable, not just print it out